# Django template render a nested dict with tuples

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, nested-loops

Here's my dict =

```
{
'123': {'metric_1': [('url_1', 'caption_1'), ('url_2', 'caption_2'), ('url_3', 'caption_3'), ('url_4', 'caption_4')], 'metric_2': [('url_1', 'caption_1'), ('url_2', 'caption_2'), ('url_3', 'caption_3'), ('url_4', 'caption_4')]}, 
'456': {'metric_1': [('url_1', 'caption_1'), ('url_2', 'caption_2'), ('url_3', 'caption_3'), ('url_4', 'caption_4')], 'metric_2': [('url_1', 'caption_1'), ('url_2', 'caption_2'), ('url_3', 'caption_3'), ('url_4', 'caption_4')]},
'789': {'metric_1': [('url_1', 'caption_1'), ('url_2', 'caption_2'), ('url_3', 'caption_3'), ('url_4', 'caption_4')], 'metric_2': [('url_1', 'caption_1'), ('url_2', 'caption_2'), ('url_3', 'caption_3'), ('url_4', 'caption_4')]}, 
}
```

it basically is a dict of a dict of a list of tuples.

what I'd like to render via Django template is:

```
123
metric_1
url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4

metric_2
url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4


456
metric_1
url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4

metric_2
url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4


789
metric_1
url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4

metric_2
url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4
```

but I'm not able to do so, here's my current Django template:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 p-2">
{% for one_analysis_id, all_metrics in url_dict.items %}
<table>
    <tr><p>Analysis ID: {{ one_analysis_id }}</p></tr>
    {% for metric_name, url_and_caption_tuple_list in all_metrics.items %}
        <tr><p>{{ metric_name }}</p></tr>
        <tr>
        {% for url_and_caption_tuple in url_and_caption_tuple_list %}
            <td><img width="350" height="300" src="{{ url_and_caption_tuple.0 }}"><div>{{ url_and_caption_tuple.1 }}</div></td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

What the above code renders is:

```
123
metric_1
metric_2
url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4

url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4


456
metric_1
metric_2
url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4

url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4


789
metric_1
metric_2
url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4

url_1        url_2        url_3       url_4
caption_1    caption_2    caption_3   caption_4
```

Could anyone please provide any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but I would handle that "restructuring logic" inside of the view and pass the data to the template in a handy format.

Comment: The data structure is set, my question is seeking advice for the "restructuring logic" of the view after my own efforts so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not promoting this way of doing it, but it is a working solution:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 p-2">
  {% for one_analysis_id, all_metrics in url_dict.items %}
  <table class="table">
    <tr><th>Analysis ID: {{ one_analysis_id }}</th></tr>
    {% for metric_name, url_and_caption_tuple_list in all_metrics.items %}
    <tr><th>{{ metric_name }}</th></tr>
    <tr>
      {% for url_and_caption_tuple in url_and_caption_tuple_list %}
      <td>{{ url_and_caption_tuple.0 }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      {% for url_and_caption_tuple in url_and_caption_tuple_list %}
      <td>{{ url_and_caption_tuple.1 }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

As I said already in the comments, this would better be handled inside of the view's logic and be passed to the template in an easily digestible format.